# Attributes of my Time dimension table in star schema

Tags: sql, uml, data-warehouse, star-schema

I'm building a DW with a star schema modeling. I'll use it for a BI project with pentaho.
I'll have of course a time dimension table. I'll analyze my fact table with differents granularity (day, week, month year, perhaps other)

Should I put one attribute for each of those granularity in my dimension table (so I have one day attribute, one month attribute, one year attribute ...) or should I just write the date and then calculate everything with this date (get the month of the date, the year of the date ...)?

thks a lot for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would add the attributes of the dates as their own columns. This does not take up significantly more space, and generally gives the query optimiser a better shot at working out how many of the dimension table records match a given criterion (for example, that the day_of_month = 31).

Comment: thks a lot it was what I thought.

Perhaps a last detail. Should I write every attributes (date, week, month, year) and also a date attribute, or does this one is useless?

Comment: Carpet bomb the dimension table with just about everything you can think of, including the date.

Comment: English is not for my language, does "carpet bomb" is a positive or negative term???

Comment: Ah sorry! http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carpet_bombing In this case what I mean is to add all of the attributes without thinking too hard about them. The downside of adding another attribute that you end up not needing is less than the downside of not adding an attribute that you later find that you needed.

Comment: ok so more is good.

Well at least I learned a new expression and I have the answer of my question today :)

Comment: The origin of "carpet bomb" as used informally in contexts like these is vaguely ironic.  It's difficult to explain to an English speaker, let alone someone whose primary language is not English.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to day, week, month, and year,  you should think of other attributes like "company holiday", or "fiscal quarter".  This can be an enormous resource for driving the same query off of different time windows.

Answer (score 0):

Typically, the more, the merrier.

Here is an example I'm using...

> ledger@localhost->  select * from date_dimension where date = '2015-12-25';
>
> -[ RECORD 1 ]----+--------------------
>
> date             | 2015-12-25
>
> year             | 2015
>
> month            | 12
>
> monthname        | December
>
> day              | 25
>
> dayofyear        | 359
>
> weekdayname      | Friday
>
> calendarweek     | 52
>
> formatteddate    | 25. 12. 2015
>
> quartal          | Q4
>
> yearquartal      | 2015/Q4
>
> yearmonth        | 2015/12
>
> yearcalendarweek | 2015/52
>
> weekend          | Weekday
>
> americanholiday  | Holiday
>
> austrianholiday  | Holiday
>
> canadianholiday  | Holiday
>
> period           | Christmas season
>
> cwstart          | 2015-12-21
>
> cwend            | 2015-12-27
>
> monthstart       | 2015-12-01
>
> monthend         | 2015-12-31 00:00:00

It's based on queries from the PostgreSQL wiki here...  https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Date_and_Time_dimensions

It would be interesting to augment this with further things:

- Religious days (Easter, some of the numerous Saints' days, Ramadan, Jewish festivals, etc)
- Statutory holidays for relevant jurisdictions.  The firm I work for winds up publicizing Irish banking holidays because a number of the customers pay via bank transfers.
- If you operate in France, you might want Lundi, Mardi, Mercredi, ... rather than English day names.
- Daylight Savings Time (as true/false) would be a nice addition.